# Validating user against AD Group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

Have a scenario to verify logged in User is belong to AD Group mentioned in web.config. The code used below is working fine, but taking lot of time when looping through. (Some case User has relation of 100+ group in AD)string.

Is there a way to achieve this with direct method for better performance.

Note: I have tried Contains() method of Group obj, but could not pass string as input.

```
allowedRoles = "Role1, Role2"; //Read from web.config
string[] allowedRolesList = allowedRoles.Split(',');
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, UserDomain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,IdentityType.SamAccountName,SLID);
if (user != null)
{
    var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
    foreach (string allowedrole in allowedRolesList)
    {
        foreach (GroupPrincipal group in groups)
        {
            if (group.Name.ToLower() == allowedrole.ToLower())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `groups`..? if it's an string[] array, then you can still do the `.Contains()`

Comment: I am not sure this solution could gain performance but it might make your method more "useful". You could do something like string[] allowedRolesList = allowedRoles.ToLower().Split(',');  then in your If statement do return groups.Select(p=>p.Name.ToLower()).Intersect(allowedRolesList).Any()  This will compare two string lists, group names and Allowed roles.  If a value in one matches the other, your .Any() method should be true,  also the result of the intersect could give you a separate list of Matching values, so instead of bool return a matching results list.

Comment: You can specify group SID in web.config instead of group name, then query user tokenGroups attribute via LDAP\ADSI and check, if it contains that sid. That will also solve problems in case if the group will be renamed